# SurveyJS: How to manipulate/organize the answers JSON format to group data points?

Tags: surveyjs

I am trying to organize the SurveyJS output JSON in certain way to minimize the amount of data cleaning I need to do on backend.

I am hoping to change this:

```
answers:{
   answer1:'hello"
   answer2: 'goodbye',
   answer3: 'ciao'
}
```

Into the following:

```
answers:{
 group1:{
   answer1:'hello"
 },
 group2: {
   answer2: 'goodbye',
   answer3: 'ciao'
 }
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!!!

I've tried using valueName=group1 and valuePropertyName=group1 on each element to no avail.

Comment: How do you know which answer belongs to which group?

Comment: I know beforehand, like questions about car tagged with 'car' and questions about boats tagged with 'boats.